# Problem about planes

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Say we have $2x+3y+3z=0$ which is a plane.
Does that plane have infinite dimensions (it is a 2D "object" — forgive me as I am not a mathematician — but each side has infinite length) or is it just the parallelogram that is defined by the vectors $[2,3,3]$ and $[x,y,z]$?

I think its the first one because the solution to that equation is all the vectors that are perpendicular to $[2,3,3]$ which are infinite.

Comment: What is your definition of dimension? Of infinite dimensions?

Comment: If you are asking if the plane is unbounded, indeed it is. Equivalently in this case the area of the plane thus described is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if the plane is unbounded, indeed it is. Equivalently in this case the area of the plane thus described is infinite.

Comment: How's everything going in Krypton?

Comment: With Bruce planning to visit, I'm cleaning up the Fortress.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different types of/ definitions of dimensions in Mathematics. As a vector space, the plane (since it goes through the origin) is 2-dimensional, in the sense that every vector in the plane can be written as the linear combination of two vectors. In another sense, the dimension is 2, in that, if you know the value of any two of the coordinates of a point in the plane, you can uniquely locate the point in the plane. Sorry, but this is an intrinsically-technical issue and I cant see how to avoid bring up the different definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The parallelogram defined by [2,3,3] and [x,y,z] does not make sense because you don't know what [x,y,z] are permissible (that is what you are trying to find out!) . It is the first one: all solutions to the equation are on the plane (by definition).